# Extending a measurable function to Riemann sphere

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

For context I am looking at disjoint components of the Riemann sphere that map to one another injectively by a rational map $R$. i.e. we have the chain $$U_0 \xrightarrow{R} U_1 \xrightarrow{R} U_2 \xrightarrow{R} ...$$ where $R\vert_{U_i}:U_i \rightarrow U_{i+1}$ is injective.

Suppose I have some measureable function $\widetilde{\mu}:U_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

I consider the equivalence relation on $\widetilde{\mathbb{C}}:$ $$x \sim y \iff R^n (x)=R^m(y)$$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. (Here $R^n$ denotes the $n-$fold iteration of $R$). Since the $U_i$ are pairwise disjoint and $R\vert_{U_i}$ are injective, at most one point in $U_0$ can be in an equivalence class.

I define the function $\mu:\widetilde{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as follows: for $p\in\widetilde{\mathbb{C}}$, $\mu(p)=0$ if $[p] \cap U_0 = \emptyset$ and $\mu(p)=\widetilde{\mu}(q)$ if $[p]\cap U_0 = \{q\}$.

I want to show that this function defined is also measureable, but I am not entirely sure how. I was thinking of considering $\mu$ on each of the $U_i$ and showing that was measureable... but I don't really know how to go about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "component" here? The Riemann Sphere is connected and thus has only one component.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I am talking about Fatou components specifically

Comment: Forget your $U_n$ other than $U_0$ and just consider the sets $U_n' = R^n(U_0)$, and their union $U$. These are pairwise disjoint as well, and $\mu$ is defined by $$\mu(x) = \begin{cases}0&x \notin U\\\tilde \mu(R^n(x))& x \in U_n\end{cases}$$ While $\tilde\mu$ depends only on $U_0$, $\mu$ depends on $\Bbb C$, so you need to relate measurability on $U_0$ to that on $\Bbb C$. In particular, you need to know that $U_0$ is a measurable set. $R$ is continuous, so that should be enough.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being pedantic, I just have a couple of question. Do you mean that if $x \in U_n$, then $\mu(x) = \tilde{\mu}(R^{-n} (x))$? Also, this may be silly, but is it not possible for there for be a point $x$ not in any $U_n$ that intersects $U_0$ in its orbit, for example the backwards orbit. Finally, are you indexing these $U_n$ with $n$ in the integers? Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I meant $U_n'$ - i.e. the image of $U_0$ under $R^n$. As I said, for this, you might as well ignore your $U_n, n\ne 0$, which don't play any role in defining $\mu$, other than happening to be supersets of the sets that actually are important in defining $\mu$, which are those images.  And yes, it should have been $\tilde\mu\circ R^{-n}$ Properly stated, my definition is identical in content to your definition.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you very much